# How to return all the address values from all keys in the map

Tags: scala

```
case class Company(name: String, locations: List[Location])
case class Location(name: String, address: String)

val m = Map[String, Location](....)
```

How can I return a list of all the addresses for all the keys?

I tried this so far, but it isn't working:

```
   val addressValues: List[String] =  m.mavValues(x => x.locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

**you would need to `.map` and get the location, which will give you `Iterable[Location]`**

```
scala> val m = Map[String, Location]("prayagupd" -> Location("First hill", "England"), 
                                     "blankman"  -> Location("Blank hill", "Blank States"))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Location] = Map(prayagupd -> Location(First hill,England), blankman -> Location(Blank hill,Blank States))

scala> m.map { case (name, location) => location }
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Location] = List(Location(First hill,England), Location(Blank hill,Blank States))
```

If you need the location names,

```
scala> m.map { case (_, location) => location.name }
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(First hill, Blank hill)
```

**Or, you can simply do `.values` which gives `Iterable[Location]` too,**

```
scala> m.values
res2: Iterable[Location] = MapLike.DefaultValuesIterable(Location(First hill,England), Location(Blank hill,Blank States))
```

Comment: On a Map `values` function returns all values so no need to use `map` for that.

Answer (score 0):

`val addressValues: List[String] =  m.values.map(_.address).toList`
Look at types and [api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html). `mapValues` returns new `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

On a `Map` the `.values` function returns an `Iterable` of all values.

```
> val m1: Map[String, Location] = ???
> m1.values
res0: Iterable[Location] = MapLike(Location(..))
```

Or if you have a `Map[String, Company]`

```
> val m2: Map[String, Company] = ???
> m2.mapValues(_.locations).values.flatten
res1: Iterable[Location] = List(Location(..))
```